# How to navigate on items/details on JqeuryMobile List

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have some items on a JqueryMobile List selected from a table of an SQLite db, when I press on any of this items i want to select its details. Since JqueryMobile can't handle multiple pages and i dont know how to pass parameters between pages and I don't know how do it with one  html page, I'm asking for some help or an example on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery-mobile can handle 'virtual' multiple pages:

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page1">
    <!-- page content -->
  </div>
  <div data-role="page2">
    <!-- page content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

and access them via anchors - it will simply hide the visibility of the one not selected:

```
<a href="#page1">
```

...but you can simply pass on variables as url- parameters like:

```
<a href="nextsite.html?parameter1=1&parameter2=2" rel="external">pass some parameters</a>
```

(watch the rel=external when referring to a new page) and then reading these like that:

```
var parameter1 = getUrlVars()["parameter1"];
var parameter2 = getUrlVars()["parameter2"];
```

whereas the getUrlVars() function reads:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var url = window.location.toString();
        url = url.split('#')[0];
        var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
return vars;
}

    return vars;
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks Chris! I ended up using SessionStorage to save the id, since I didn't want to use "rel=external" But it is a good way to do it.